# Function extension problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is a compact set, with 'normal' Euclidean distance. As I know, since it's compact, then there must be a ball $B(R,\vec{0}) \subset A$ for some $R > 0$. Then there's a set $S = \{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m: \forall j = 1,\dots,m: |x_j| \leq R \} \subset B(R,\vec{0})$ which is also compact.

Now assume that $f$ is continuous at $A$. I wonder if it's possible to extend function $f$ to set $S$ such that it's continuous at $S$.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe oh wow, I haven't seen that theorem before, thanks!